# QGIS 1.8.0 Mac can't create ring

Tags: qgis, editing, mac

Can anyone spot what is wrong here? I've selected single feature, the existing rings are obvious, it's not intersecting anything (even a feature in another layer...

http://johnsankey.ca/ringerror.jpg

Comment: Obviously no answer, so submitted it as a bug.

Comment: This is known to be a bug: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/7401